# Can I have an empty else php

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am working in `wordpress` and there is a function that is calling for a `CSS` sheet specific to my template.

Now I have a second template that has a different style sheet.

The current function is an if statement (i.e., if template A, use `CSS` sheet A),
but now I would like to do an if/elseif statement that looks for template A or template B. This way I don't have to write the if statement twice.

I want to know what to do with the else at the end. Can I just leave that blank, or is there a better way to handle that?

Comment: Just don't use an `else`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to define an `else` condition. You can just have `if` or `if/elseif` if you want. Here's a reference - http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php

Do you want anything to happen if you are not on Template A or Template B?  If not, simply exclude the `else` statement, and use a conditional like

```
if ($template-a) {
    // include template a css
} elseif ($template-b) {
    // include template b css
}
```

If you'd prefer some default behavior happen if you are not on Template A or Template B, use a conditional like

```
if ($template-a) {
    // include template a css
} elseif ($template-b) {
    // include template b css
} else {
    // include default css or whatever
}
```

Comment: That's about what I thought, but I didn't want to create any problems on a clients site. Thank you!